# Parse Issue in AppDelegate.h

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the following code block, as the content of my `AppDelegate.h` of an iOS one view application:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.h
//  kompas
//
//  Created by Attention8 Aps on 2/6/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Attention8. All rights reserved.
// 

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;



@end
```

This yields the error "Expected identifed or '('" on the line 
    @class ViewController

I have tried comparing it with the AppDelegate.h from a newly started project, but I can't for the love of god spot the error. The mistake has arisen after tinkering with other files, but I can't seem to locate this issue.

Any help as to what could be the cause of this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a problem with another file. Try going through all your other classes and getting rid of any warnings/errors with them.

Comment: I cleaned out my warnings, which I probably should have done for starters. A good pointer, but to no avail, after building clean and rebuilding I still get the same error. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Try build and analyze? And you're sure there are no warnings or errors on any other files?

Comment: Build and analyze yielded no new insights. Still just the one Issue in AppDelegate.h.

Comment: It was error in another file, a leading * in one of the files. I thought I had scoured my project for these errors as lots of people on stackoverflow reported this for use. Thank you for you effort. Walks off in shame.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open this file in vi. Sometimes invisible characters causes such errors.

Comment: usually invisible characters result in `stray '\357' in program` errors.